# Characterizing Subgroups through Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Just for fun, I was wondering how one could specify subgroups using homomorphism equations. For instance, for vector spaces, every subspace can be specified as the kernel of some homomorphism. For nonabelian groups, this isn't the case. You can only get normal subgroups this way. But suppose $f,g$ are two homomorphisms from $G$ to some group $H$. Then the set $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ is a group. This group does not have to be normal in $G$. For instance, if $g$ were the identity isomorphism on $G$ and $f$ was conjugation by some element $t$ then the equation is $txt^{-1} = x$ or $tx = xt$ so the set is just the centralizer of $x$.

My question is, is there a word for equations like this? Can any subgroup be generated by something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the construction you are describing is called the *equalizer* of $f,g$. More correctly, the equalizer is a group $E$ and a homomorphism $e: E \to G$, such that if we have any group homomorphism $h: X \to G$ with $f\circ h = g \circ h$, then there is a unique homomorphism $m: X \to E$ such that $h = e \circ m$ (if $h$ equalizes $f$ and $g$ it "factors through $e$").

You may be interested to try to convince yourself that $e$ is injective, and so defines a subgroup of $G$, up to isomorphism.

Of course, a more general way of defining a subgroup is simply as an injective homomorphism into $G$ (this does not give a "true" subgroup : for example, we have an injective homomorphism:

$\exp: \Bbb Z_4 \to \Bbb C$ given by:

$\exp([k]_4) = e^{\pi ki/2}$, but obviously $\Bbb Z_4$ isn't even a *subset* of the complex numbers).

I believe that in groups, every subgroup arises as an equalizer, but I don't recall off-hand the proof.